Window Service takes more time than its configured interval
I have developed a Windows service that will run at every minute, and I am testing it with large sets of data. While executing service logic, I also add logs in files as well.
This is my code:
public partial class TaskAccessGrandRevokeService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public TaskAccessGrandRevokeService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; //For SSL
            int interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TaskAccessGrandRevokeServiceTimerInterval"]);

            UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile("\nTaskAccessGrandRevokeService: Service started at " + DateTime.Now);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = interval; //time interval in milliseconds (1 minute) 
            timer.Enabled = true;

            OnElapsedTime(null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile($"\nTaskAccessGrandRevokeService: {DateTime.Now} \nError:{ex.Message}-{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile("\nTaskAccessGrandRevokeService stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile($"\nTaskAccessGrandRevokeService: API called at {DateTime.Now}");
            TaskRepo.ManageUserAccess().Wait();
            UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile($"\nTaskAccessGrandRevokeService: API call completed at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile($"\nYTaskAccessGrandRevokeService: {DateTime.Now} \nError:{ex.InnerException}-{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

}

TaskRepo.ManageUserAccess().Wait(); is taking more than 1 minute to execute, so the next minute, the service again executes the same logic and I get another occurrence logs but I am not able to get the logs which are after TaskRepo.ManageUserAccess().Wait(); line.
public static class UtilityHelper
{
    public static void WriteTextToFile(string Message)
    {
        string checkPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\LogsFile";

        if (!Directory.Exists(checkPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(checkPath);
        }

        string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\LogsFile\\WindowsServiceLogs_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy").Replace('-', '_') + ".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.   
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }

        }
    }
}

I want to know that how can I get those missing logs that currently I am not getting in my text file.
Thank you for any type suggestion, help.

You dont have any guarantee that the process being called is flushing its logs to disk until the process ends, as we cannot see the implementation details of UtilityHelper.WriteTextToFile. Id recommend adopting a time-based naming standard for the log files, similar to that used by IIS HTML logging. This means you will be able to access log files as their name will change based on a time interval.

@PhillipH I have added code for WriteTextToFile

Try adding sw.Flush() after each writeline to make sure data gets sent.  There are timers that do the flush which may wait until a buffer contains a minimum amount of data.

@jdweng sometime I am getting error that service did not start in timely fashion any suggestion on that ?

Check the Windows Event Logs.  You need to get Credentials from Password Server and random errors like this are often due to Server not responding.

@jdweng sw.flush not working.Still not getting logs

The data must be getting sent.  The issue is reading.  Maybe you are getting two messages in one event.

@jdweng Okay sometime I am getting errors in logs file that the file cannot be access because it is used by another process. Any help for that.

You are failing on the Write and the exception is trying to write a 2nd time while the file is still open.  Other apps are running at the same time your app and not allowing your app to run.  So you timer is expiring or the write time in your app is longer than the timeout (or both).
